# How to match key and value in a Typescript lookup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lookup

UPDATE:

Thanks to @OliverRadini for getting me there. Following from their response I have a solution that works in my case. The only problem I had with their answer was that I needed to externally type what you're passing into the function but couldn't figure out a way to infer the key without it being in a function. In my case it's fine to use a util to do that for us, as follows:

```js
interface ITest {
  n: number;
  b: boolean;
}

const f = <K extends keyof ITest>(x: { id: K; params: ITest[K] }) => ({
  ...x,
  _propToConfirmYourUsingTheUtilNeverWriteThisManually: true,
});

type Props = ReturnType<typeof f>;

const a: Props = f({ id: "n", params: 1 }); // no type error
const b: Props = f({ id: "n", params: true }); // Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'number'

const c = f({ id: "b", params: true }); // no type error
const d = f({ id: "b", params: 1 }); // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

// Errors because we didn't add _propToConfirmYourUsingTheUtilNeverWriteThisManually
// This ridiculously named prop should ensure we don't override it without noticing
const z: Props = {
  // Property '_propToConfirmYourUsingTheUtilNeverWriteThisManually' is missing in type ...
  id: "b",
  params: 7,
};

f(a); // no type error
f(b); // no type error
f(c); // no type error
f(d); // no type error
```

---

UPDATE:

It's okay for this case to pass:

```js
const invalidProps1: Props<IdsWithParameters> = {
  id: "id1",
  params: {
    param1: "string",
  },
};
```

Additional properties aren't a problem with the code outside of this. But for this component function to be able to be generic and take any id in `IdsWithParameters` we can't specify the key explicitly like `Props<'id1'>` as in @oliverradini reply. But their help has led me to this which is close but still not quite there.

```
interface Props<K extends keyof IdsWithParameters> {
  id: K;
  params: IdsWithParameters[K];
}

// Somehow want Props to know what is being used as the id and infer 
// the correct params type
function Text(props: Props) {
  const text = intlFunctionThatGetsTheTranslatedText(props.id, props.params);

  return <>{text}</>
}
```

---

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm building a library where I need to allow people to create an object (the IdsWithParameters interface) specifying allowed keys and the typed parameters allowed to go along with each specific key. In various places they will want to specify an object that has and `id` and `params` (The Props interface) that match 1 specific key/value pair from the IdsWithParameters instance.

I can get to a point using a lookup where you must pass in a valid key and params to the Props instance. But can't figure out how to limit the params to be the ones that match the given key/id.

```js
interface IdsWithParameters {
  id1: {};
  id2: {
    param1: string;
  };
  id3: {
    param2: boolean;
    param3: number;
  };
}

interface Props<I extends IdsWithParameters> {
  id: keyof I;
  params: I[keyof I];
}

// This works as expected
const validProps1: Props<IdsWithParameters> = {
  id: "id1",
  params: {},
};

// This works as expected
const validProps2: Props<IdsWithParameters> = {
  id: "id2",
  params: {
    param1: "string",
  },
};

const invalidProps1: Props<IdsWithParameters> = {
  id: "id1",
  // Want this to error, saying that params should be {} but it passes
  params: {
    param1: "string",
  },
};

const invalidProps2: Props<IdsWithParameters> = {
  id: "id2",
  // Want this to error, saying that params should be { param1: string; } but it passes
  params: {},
};
```

I feel like I've been looking at this for too long and there's either a simple way of doing it or a much better solution and I can't see it anymore. For context I'm building a package for handling translatable content strings in React packages. So it could be used like so:

```js
// IdsWithParameters in above example
interface ContentStringsWithAcceptableParameters {
  "errors.404.title": {},
  "errors.404.content": {
     pageUrl: string;
  },
  "errors.retryAttemptsLeft": {
    attemptsLeft: number;
  }
}

interface Props<I extends ContentStringsWithAcceptableParameters> {
  id: keyof I;
  params: I[keyof I];
}

// The react component we'll be using
function Text(props: Props<ContentStringsWithAcceptableParameters>) {
  const text = intlFunctionThatGetsTheTranslatedText(props.id, props.params);

  return <>{text}</>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can understand what we're trying to do if we simplify the example a little:

```js
interface ITest {
  n: number;
  b: boolean;
}

const f = <K extends keyof ITest>(
  x: {
    id: K,
    params: ITest[K],
  },
) => true;

f({ id: 'n', params: 1 });    // no type error
f({ id: 'n', params: true }); // Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'number'

f({ id: 'b', params: true }); // no type error
f({ id: 'b', params: 1 });    // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

We can specify that some generic (`K` in the example above) extends a key of the type. Then we can use that key to get the type we're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Makes sense. In my use case I've just realised it doesn't actually matter if you supply additional properties , so the example case `invalidProps1` doesn't actually need to error for me. The issue I have is that the function that makes use of the `Props` interface shouldn't be given a specific key e.g. `Props<"id1">` as it's a generic function that can take any id. I'll update the issue with this, as you answer does mostly solve what I originally asked.

Comment: @CharlieJackson Ah, ok - but the function would take the id?

Comment: Yes the function would. There are other places where you'd want to define an object to be of this type outside of the function e.g. A selector that returns one of these objects. So a solution that relies on inferring the key from the function may not fully solve the issue if that's where you were thinking.

Comment: @CharlieJackson That makes a bit more sense - so you need to be able to define some type that has an `id` property as one of the keys of `IdsWithParameters`, and a `params` which has the type which matches the type of that id-property on `IdsWithParameters`?

Comment: Yes, you're much better at simplifying the explanation than me 

Comment: Ha well it's a bit easier to get to the bottom of the problem when you're outside of it, I think. I've rewritten my answer - but I guess it still doesn't get you what you need - maybe you can provide some additional information from here in terms of what is left to achieve that you need?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I just updated the issue with how it can be solved in my case. Using your answer but with 1 slight adjustment so I can type objects outside of using them immediately. Thanks again. I can stop beating my head against the wall

Comment: @CharlieJackson Glad you got it solved! Hope the answers helped on the way a little